# Error of deriving the variable cross section rod wave equation

Tags: waves, differentiation, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

On page $519$ of the book *Engineering Vibration* (which can be downloaded from [here](https://www.academia.edu/43145437/Engineering_Vibration_Fourth_Edition)), the following wave equation of a variable cross-section rod is derived:

$${ {\partial}\over{\partial}x} \Big( EA(x){ {\partial}w(x,t)\over{\partial}x}  \Big)={\rho}A(x) { {\partial}w^2(x,t)\over{\partial}t^2}\tag{1}$$

where:

- $x$ is the spatial coordinate
- $t$ is time
- $E$ is the Young's modulus of the rod
- $A(x)$ is the variable cross-section function of the rod
- $\rho$ is the density of the rod
- $w(x,t)$ is the wave function

Because some of the steps are missing from the derivation process, I tried deriving the same equation myself but failed. Please point out my mistake.

[image]

For the variable cross-section rod in the picture above, I wrote the following dynamics equation:
$$\Big(F(x,t)+dF(x,t)\Big) - F(x,t) = \Big(dm(x)\Big){ {\partial}w^2(x,t)\over{\partial}t^2}\tag{2}$$
where $dm(x)$ is the mass of the Infinitesimal element of the rod.
Next, I crossed out the forces $F(x,t)$ and defined the mass $dm(x)$ as a product of volume $dV(x)$ and density:
$$dF(x,t) = {\rho}\Big(dV(x)\Big){ {\partial}w^2(x,t)\over{\partial}t^2}\tag{3}$$
Since the volume $dV(x)$ is:
$$dV(x) = A(x)dx\tag{4}$$
equation $(3)$ can be rewritten as:
$$dF(x,t) = {\rho}A(x)dx{ {\partial}w^2(x,t)\over{\partial}t^2}\tag{5}$$
After this, I defined $dF(x,t)$ as:
$$dF(x,t) = d\Big(P(x,t)A(x)\Big)=\Big(dP(x,t)\Big)A(x)+ P(x,t)\Big(dA(x)\Big)\tag{6}$$
where $P(x,t)$ is the pressure. By expanding the total derivatives, I obtained:
$$dF(x,t) = \Big( { \partial P(x,t) \over \partial x}dx +  { \partial P(x,t) \over \partial t}dt \Big)A(x) + P(x,t){ \partial A(x) \over \partial x}dx \tag{7}$$
Hook's law states:
$$P(x,t) = E{ {\partial}w(x,t)\over{\partial}x}\tag{8} $$
and because of that, I rewrote equation $(7)$ as:
$$dF(x,t) = E\Bigg(\Big( { \partial ^2 w(x,t) \over \partial x^2}dx +  { \partial ^2 w(x,t) \over \partial x \partial t}dt \Big)A(x) + w(x,t){ \partial A(x) \over \partial x}dx\Bigg) \tag{9}$$
In the end, I derived the expression:
$$E\Bigg(\Big( { \partial ^2 w(x,t) \over \partial x^2}dx +  { \partial ^2 w(x,t) \over \partial x \partial t}dt \Big)A(x) + w(x,t){ \partial A(x) \over \partial x}dx\Bigg) = {\rho}A(x)dx{ {\partial}w^2(x,t)\over{\partial}t^2}\tag{10}$$
In equation $(10)$ there is an extra term. Namely, the ${ \partial ^2 w(x,t) \over \partial x \partial t}dt$ term. If that did not exist, I would get equation $(1)$. So, my question is, why does that term not exist in equation $(1)$?

Comment: The only explanation is that the pressure on a line x=cst is constant, $\partial p(x,t)/\partial t |_{x=cst}=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in equation 2, it should be the increment in the $x$ direction, the part in parenthesis should be

$$F + \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} dx\, .$$

Also, I would probably take finite values for the size of your element: $\Delta x$. Then you can take the limit, and new derivatives appear.

Comment: You are correct. I found the solution in a nother piece of literature. Thank you Nicoguaro.